# Catch exception when adding to manytomany field in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

So I am adding a list of items to my manytomany field.

If item1 already exists in myModelInstance.myM2MField, it does not add it again.

```
myItems = [item1, item2]
```

---

```
try:
    myModelInstance.myM2MField.add(*myItems)
except Exception as e:
    return e
```

I would like to catch the list of items which were not added and return it. Is that possible?

Comment: Even if it already exists, Django won't add it again (will silently fail)

Comment: Yes I know, but I want to catch that silent fail and return response. This was not added because it already exists.

Comment: I was able to do it using  create method on intermediate table

Answer (score -2):

Check if it already exists and raise error.

if myModelInstance.myM2MField.all():

raise ()